# Entity Framework Core seed data with an Identity of 0

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to add some seed data to my model using `.HasData` in order to populate my database.  I use ID 0 within my data model to map to unknown on each table.

When trying to run the application once adding this, I get the following error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'DboTable' cannot be added because
>   there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.

I assumed that EFCore forces a value of null since a integer of 0 is equivalent to null, but when I try to force an integer parse, it still throws the same error.

At this point I'm unsure of how to approach this, any advice would be appreciated.

**snippit from DbContext.cs**

```
...
entity.HasData(new DboTable()
{
    Id = 0,               // integer
    Label = "UNKNOWN",    // string
    ...
});
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that EF Core 2.1 doesn't support a PK value of 0.

Unfortunately, any seed data trying to use a value of 0 for a PK will have to run a migration with custom SQL to insert their PK 0 records.

see: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12399

Answer (score 1):

I have created little "hack" to **bypass 0 PK value restriction** after I reverse engineering the [EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore) code and I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/0ba65b8dfc9294b714b6855eef340bdfbfb8d64c/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/ModelValidator.cs#L884) line of code.

Here is my snipped extension code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;

namespace EntityFrameworkCore.CustomMigration
{
    public static class CustomModelBuilder
    {
        public static bool IsSignedInteger(this Type type)
           => type == typeof(int)
              || type == typeof(long)
              || type == typeof(short)
              || type == typeof(sbyte);

        public static void Seed<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class
        {
            var entnty = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();

            var pk = entnty.Metadata
                .GetProperties()
                .FirstOrDefault(property => 
                    property.RequiresValueGenerator() 
                    && property.IsPrimaryKey()
                    && property.ClrType.IsSignedInteger()
                    && property.ClrType.IsDefaultValue(0)
                );
            if (pk != null)
            {
                entnty.Property(pk.Name).ValueGeneratedNever();
                entnty.HasData(data);
                entnty.Property(pk.Name).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            }
            else
            {
                entnty.HasData(data);
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Seed(new List<Tenant> {
        new Tenant() {TenantID = 0 , Name = string.Empty},
        new Tenant() {TenantID = 1 , Name = "test"}
        //....
        );

    //....
}
```